# Creating new images

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision

I would like to create new images of landscapes with deep neural network. If my input is a large dataset of pictures of landscapes, how can I do to output new pictures of landscapes ? Which techniques do you recommend ?

Comment: this is  a broad and vague question it should be nailed down to specifics

Comment: @NikosM. Hey, thank you for your comment. To be more specific, I have a dataset of landscape pictures, and from this dataset, I would like to feed a neural network. The Neural Network should be able to identify different patterns in landscapes (rivers, mountains, trees..) and from that, output one or multiple pictures similar to the input (but still different from the input, otherwise there is no point of doing that). So I'm asking how to create such a Neural Network, I hope I've been specific enough.

Comment: please add details to the question by using the `edit` function

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used used Deep Learning method to create new images looking like real one is GAN (Generative adversarial network).

The idea is to train in the same time 2 neural networks : one aiming at creating images as close as possible to the real ones (Generator), and the other one aiming at guessing if the image is a true one or a generated one (Discriminator).

The Generator will then learn how to fool the Discriminator, which will imporve because of the feedback from the Generator. When the result is good enough, you just keep the Generator to generate close-to-reality images.

GANs are an advanced technology, and are not easy to use : they are advanced neural networks, so this is not an easy problem for someone new to DataScience (as you seem to be). You should try to find more info around the subject.